# writing a vector from c++ code into a file and then reading it in matlab

Tags: c++, matlab

I have a vector of data type double generated in c++ and I am trying to write it into a text file so that I can then load the text file into matlab in order to plot the data from the vector versus data that is already in my matlab workspace. I am able to create a file called real_data2.txt, and the program runs without an error, but then when I try to load the file in Matlab or open it in a text reader, the contents of the file is gibberish so-to-speak. The code that I am using to create the file is:

```
ofstream out("real_data2.txt");
    if(!out){
        cout << "Cannot open file.\n";
        return;
    }
for(int i = 0; i<N; i++){
    out.write((char *) &out2[i][0], N);
}
out.close();
```

where N is the length of out2. This successfully generates the 'real_data2.txt' file. I then put the generated file into the matlab path and use `A = textread('real_data2.txt'`) in matlab to try to read the file. The error message that I receive is:

> Error using data read
>   Trouble reading number from file (row 1, field 1) ==>
>   > Uíl¯9@9ÊÝÖ(@9Ò»=£P<@¨CÁ\n
>
> Error in textread (line 175)
>   [varargout{1:nlhs}]=dataread('file',varargin{:}); %#ok

and when I double click the txt file I get a file containing text like:

>Uíl¯9@9ÊÝÖ(@9Ò»=£P<@¨CÁ

> '`C@Bw|N¯8@]H~=@7@7ÂÙjóõ?ñXéWSO@¹U¥A°õ¿»DÂ¾;@@Â¡Ô¨ÊëQÀw®nr!úU@ß7XÀjw©}NÀJA(×FÀ|ûó>%÷GÀa¬W¯7@·âÖ3Ð`ÀÉ¿*x¨G@Ï¿U°ÜÁ6@ò5^->@qzáme[ÀKÆ]T^'À¼7CJK@EhúôP:ÀF¼¸ý@íÀ÷¾§ÎC@2w©^=AÀÛ«½ñðúr@    >ò(÷@BË¶xÀË6Y7¸@s÷ãCÀ<µ}`lÀ<uÄòÚtÀêGÂ0KZÀ~iò*~@$áu@Àq>¢ÒE{@Õbp«^8DÀ4©@Ëçc@nê'È1ÀÑJ5|@$éEy`ÀUßÎzí@,u°<ä@^Q4íbÀ4õÆÚ@6S8(*ÀD$°ä?u@kn|½Àz
>   >ÓvÀ'F@ôuc@þÃjàÂ:À KµÕv@ý/úÁL]ÀvÂ°¶ó+R@íæ¿¥òC@ðvwjc@WÔÙjÀ¡@y¿ò5d®I@M¸ö/þät@ZÝd>@Cåh0~ÀLÛoE@cÜ¼Â¥À§ÝY.^ÀÃ¹}øDzÀß®H\XÀ¦ähöT~@ÍÚ\åþÀá@Êà¤Ï»TÀAýx@­r$Ü@u@Bã¿ l@ß
>   xç@½ô¶ %ÖbÀ{Ì±Àò#@HëSuÀ[ÙÑóÏ)w@ zû%ÀGK«7qiÀÅ¦ÊoÀúxeIÀy8nÓV@ØÕ3~yÀ³   >ú¹@vc@ñáÄ¶mÀ&Q¹ig@?klgmÀ`Ìh&ûu@J    «kGiÀÂ|7kê@y-* @ªôg@ïíEY@\Ayi?S\@eØ¸hã@ðô6fzÀ
>   ©ås¬·@ROÅÍjÀÓâÒ×SJ Àýßv¨b
>   >À(Ê-  ß¸Àów Ás@ûöÅèÀj¦Ðî@©
>   ÎÀ¾&ñ~.U@_ÿz<~@qådøIÛz@4)Áe@:´N{À=ào¸@ÆlëíVÒÀ©ÀÍûY7|­XÀ¬' Çä1ÀØ@ÁÇj@®¨k8À¨

Any ideas where I am going wrong? I don't know much about this topic, but I am assuming that it has something to do with trying to cast the location of the data to a char pointer but I am not sure and wouldn't know how to get around that since I have tried altering that line unsuccessfully with things like `out.write((char *) out2[i][0], N);` and `out.write((double *) &out2[i][0], N);` which I realize now might not make too much sense...Anyways, any help would be greatly appreciated! Let me know if you know how to fix this problem!

Comment: You're writing your data as binary (raw double values) - you need to write it as text. Use std::cout, not write().

Comment: What you are doing there is totally not what you want. First of all you have to know what you really want to write. Do you need all the values from the vector as text separated by a space or linebreak(like "3.14 2.15 5.433")?

Comment: either write `double` (_binary_) into your file, then read them as such from matlab (this will be the fastest if you only want to read the points to plot them). If you want to be able to read the file in a text format (so not only with matlab), you have first to convert your `double` to their string representation, then write them into a file.

Comment: you could also use file.h and fprintf to get the doubles into a human readable form

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
out << out2[i][0];
```

is the correct way.

Your output is binary.

Comment: Very simple, perfect answer! Thank you! I wanted the values in the file to be separated by spaces which I didn't specify in the question, so I just had to use `out << out2[i][0]<<" ";` instead :). The simple nature of this answer and the comments above really highlight how undeveloped my coding abilities are...Thanks everyone for your responses!